# convert two dimensional array to multiple single arrays

Tags: php

I have a two dimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => john
        )
    [dept] => Array
        (
            [0] => val_1
            [1] => val_2
        )
    [to] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
            [1] => two
        )
)
```

Is there anyway I can convert this array to multiple single arrays like the following:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => john
    [dept] => val_1
    [to] => one
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => john
    [dept] => val_1
    [to] => two
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => john
    [dept] => val_2
    [to] => one
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => john
    [dept] => val_2
    [to] => two
)
```

I used array_merge but failed to get what I exactly want. Any help is appreciated

Comment: i think you should redesign your array structure...this looks really bad

Comment: Actually, it's one dimensional array, but each inner value is a comma-separated value

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the solution might not be the cleanest though!):

[→ live @ Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/JHmeaO)

```
<?php

$arr = [
    'id' => [
        1
    ],
    'name' => [
        'john'
    ],
    'dept' => [
        'val_1', 'val_2'
    ],
    'to' => [
        'one', 'two'
    ]
];

function convert($arr, $outArrCount) {
    $total = [];
    for ($i=0; $i<$outArrCount; $i++) {
        $entry = [];
        array_walk($arr, function ($val, $key) use (&$entry, $i, $outArrCount) {
            if (count($val) > 1) {
                $entry[$key] = $val[ floor((count($val) / $outArrCount) * $i) ];
            }
            else {
                $entry[$key] = $val;
            }

        });
        $total[] = $entry;
    };
    return $total;
}
var_dump(convert($arr, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function will help you to restructure you array.

```
function loopArrayMerger(array $array) {
    if (! $array) {
        return array ();
    }

    return call_user_func_array ( 'array_merge', $array );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following function helpful to answer my question:

```
function array_cartesian() {
    $_ = func_get_args();
    if(count($_) == 0)
        return array(array());
    $a = array_shift($_);
    $c = call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, $_);
    $r = array();
    foreach($a as $v)
        foreach($c as $p)
            $r[] = array_merge(array($v), $p);
    return $r;
}
```

I can use it as follows:

```
$cross = array_cartesian(
    $arr[id],
    $arr[name],
    $arr[dept],
    $arr[to]);
print_r($cross);
```